# jquery emulate click on first li item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following list of images:

```
<ul class="docs-pictures clearfix">
    <li><img data-original="../assets/img/tibet-5.jpg" src="../assets/img/thumbnails/tibet-5.jpg" alt="Potala Palace 2"></li>
    <li><img data-original="../assets/img/tibet-6.jpg" src="../assets/img/thumbnails/tibet-6.jpg" alt="Potala Palace 3"></li>
    <li><img data-original="../assets/img/tibet-7.jpg" src="../assets/img/thumbnails/tibet-7.jpg" alt="Lhasa River"></li>
    <li><img data-original="../assets/img/tibet-8.jpg" src="../assets/img/thumbnails/tibet-8.jpg" alt="Namtso 1"></li>
    <li><img data-original="../assets/img/tibet-9.jpg" src="../assets/img/thumbnails/tibet-9.jpg" alt="Namtso 2"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to simulate a click on the first image, so I did:

```
$('.docs-pictures li:first').trigger('click');
```

But it does not work.

I tried setting an `id` for the first `img`:

```
<li><img id="img1" data-original="../assets/img/tibet-5.jpg" src="../assets/img/thumbnails/tibet-5.jpg" alt="Potala Palace 2"></li>
```

And then I did:

```
$("#img1").click()
```

And it worked, but I need to do it through `<ul>` the class

Comment: Do you have any click handler attached to `li`? You could do `$('.docs-pictures li:first img').trigger('click');`

Comment: I think you need to use `$('.docs-pictures li:first img').trigger('click')`

Comment: in one you click `<li>` in other you click `<img>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are triggering click on li , while in example that worked you are triggering img

What you should do is

```
$(".does-pictures li:first img").click();
```

And that should work. Or move your trigger function to work on li.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using

```
$('.docs-pictures li').first().trigger('click');
```

You can check the .first documentation at https://api.jquery.com/first/

Here is a fiddle I created to test it : https://jsfiddle.net/c96Lueso/

Comment: `$('.docs-pictures li').first()` is the same as `$(".docs-pictures li:first")`  https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but your click event maybe not, see the example:

```js
$('li').on('click',function(){
  alert("clicked"); 
})

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.docs-pictures li:first').trigger('click');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="docs-pictures clearfix">
    <li><img data-original="../assets/img/tibet-5.jpg" src="../assets/img/thumbnails/tibet-5.jpg" alt="Potala Palace 2"></li>
    <li><img data-original="../assets/img/tibet-6.jpg" src="../assets/img/thumbnails/tibet-6.jpg" alt="Potala Palace 3"></li>
    <li><img data-original="../assets/img/tibet-7.jpg" src="../assets/img/thumbnails/tibet-7.jpg" alt="Lhasa River"></li>
    <li><img data-original="../assets/img/tibet-8.jpg" src="../assets/img/thumbnails/tibet-8.jpg" alt="Namtso 1"></li>
    <li><img data-original="../assets/img/tibet-9.jpg" src="../assets/img/thumbnails/tibet-9.jpg" alt="Namtso 2"></li>
</ul>
```